# JENKINS pass parameters as inputs to remote host script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

We have a (3) tier system for Jenkins projects and builds.
We have setup a trust relationship between worker node and remote host
via SSH plugin and keys.

```
jenkinsrh-01 = main jenkins server (gui for projects/builds, dashboard, etc)
sys-07       = worker  node  (projects / builds are run from this remote node)
raloda10     = remote host  (target of builds)
```

In the gui configuration screen at main Jenkins server (jenkinsrh-01), we have this code below for our project with hardcoded parameter values et al.
The $SCRIPT is located at remote host and we want to pass the parameter values for use by remote host script.

Build --> Execute Shell --> Command

```
#!/bin/bash

export ORACLE_USER="oracle"
export ODA_HOST="raloda10"
export DATABASE="DEV11G05"
export SCHEMA="ASA14101X5"
export COMMENT="good state archive"
export SCRIPT="/u01/app/oracle/databases/dev11g05/bod/jenky_test.sh"

sudo -i -u ${ORACLE_USER} ssh ${ODA_HOST} ${SCRIPT}
```

On the target remote host (raloda10) the contents of the target script
is a simple test to echo the values of the parameters passed to it via "export" verbiage in the build steps above. The target remote host script (jenky_test.sh) contents are;

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
echo
echo This is correct target script on remote host
echo 
echo 1. Source database: ${DATABASE}
echo 2. Name of  schema: ${SCHEMA}
echo 3. Comments: ${COMMENT}
echo
echo ${DATABASE}
echo ${SCHEMA}
echo ${COMMENT}
#
exit
```

The worker build can access the remote host, find the remote host script, and run the shell script, "jenky_test.sh".

But the issue is that none of the build parameters are passed into the jenky_test.sh script when it runs. It does not echo back the values as they are blank as evidenced in the "Console Output", below;

```
Started by user Donald Collins
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on sys-07 (SYS-07) in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/fails_Send_Jenkins_Parameters_fromSlave_as_Inputs_for_Script_on_Remote_Host
[fails_Send_Jenkins_Parameters_fromSlave_as_Inputs_for_Script_on_Remote_Host] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson7103389345936604753.sh

This is correct target script on remote host

1. Source database:
2. Name of schema:
3. Comments:
```

The console output should be showing the values of the exported variables (parameters) for lines 1,2, and 3 above.  Instead they are blank.

I've tried all sorts of various combinations of different coding for the "sudo" call in the Command step of Execute Shell. "Nothing" seems to be able to get the parameter values to be passed as inputs for jenky_test.sh on remote target host.

I'm sure I'm missing something here that is obvious as what I'm trying to do with Jenkins is "Jenkins 101" stuff ;) ...

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Donald

Comment: Your are setting the environmental variables in the local shell not the remote one. That is the issue. You will need to pass the variables as parameters to the script or set them by reading in to EOF and listing the commands before writing EOF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your local script, you a "heredoc" and so action the ssh command and read in the command to be executed on the local host to the EOF marker.

```
sudo -i -u ${ORACLE_USER} ssh ${ODA_HOST} << EOF
export ORACLE_USER="oracle"
export ODA_HOST="raloda10"
export DATABASE="DEV11G05"
export SCHEMA="ASA14101X5"
export COMMENT="good state archive"
/u01/app/oracle/databases/dev11g05/bod/jenky_test.sh
EOF
```

Comment: Hi Raman,  Thank you for taking a look a this issue and for your advice and help.

We had previously been setting up the remote environment variables but in different manner.  We were adding a 'source' call in the sudo command and pointing to the .bash_profile in oracle home, ala;

    sudo -i -u ${ORACLE_USER} ssh ${ODA_HOST} "source /home/oracle/.bash_profile ; ${SCRIPT}"

The results were the same, empty values in the console output.

But we have not tried the same via your idea with EOF markers, we shall try that and report back....

Best Regards -  Donald

Comment: Hi Raman,

Thank you, your suggestion worked!
The console output was as expected but did also issue warning;
"Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."
I will paste full output in next 2 comments and also the jenkins shell command code as we had to export the values at both the local machine (worker node, sys07) and the remote (target node, raloda10) for output to work.
(I'm having trouble getting formating to work in these replies, so it looks like crap below, sorry. I'm following, "https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting") 
Thanks again!

Comment: Condensed Console Ouput:

Started by user Donald Collins
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on sys-07 (SYS-07) in workspace ....... $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson7098082742483678924.sh

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

This is correct target script on remote host

1. Source database: DEV11G05
2. Name of schema: ASA14101X5
3. Comments: good state archive

DEV11G05
ASA14101X5
good state archive

Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Jenkins commands;

"#!/bin/bash

export ORASRC="source /home/oracle/.bash_profile" ;
export ORACLE_USER="oracle"
export ODA_HOST="raloda10"
export DATABASE="DEV11G05"
export SCHEMA="ASA14101X5"
export COMMENT="good state archive"
export SCRIPT="/u01/app/oracle/databases/dev11g05/bod/jenky_test.sh"

sudo -i -u ${ORACLE_USER} ssh ${ODA_HOST} << EOF
# export ORACLE_USER="oracle"
# export ODA_HOST="raloda10"
export DATABASE="DEV11G05"
export SCHEMA="ASA14101X5"
export COMMENT="good state archive"
export SCRIPT="/u01/app/oracle/databases/dev11g05/bod/jenky_test.sh"
${SCRIPT}
EOF

Comment: Use the -T flag with ssh to disable pseudo-tty allocation.